# macOS: How to change PATH environment variable?

Tags: python, macos, path-variables

OS:macOS Big Sur 11.1

I have uninstalled python3.8 and python3.9

but my `echo $PATH` gives:

[image: screenshot of results]

I tried to modify path variables by `vi ~/.bash_profile`, but `bash_profile` doesn't exist.

I did `touch .bash_profile` and

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

then `source ~/.bash_profile`.
But after restarting the terminal, `echo $PATH` has not changed...

How can I delete `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:` from my path variables? And which file did this message come from? Is it because I didn't uninstall python completely?

Comment: Have you checked `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: Are you sure you are running bash at all? Modern versions of macOS use zsh by default.

Comment: The `%` is a sure sign that this is, indeed, `zsh`, as is the title bar of the window.

Comment: Look at `.zprofile` or `.zshrc`.

Comment: @YangYushi I chacked **. ~/.bashrc** does not exist .
but **/etc/bashrc** shows as follow:

`# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash` is no longer the default shell in macOS. The default shell is now `zsh`; to append to PATH, you should modify `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: Awesome！！！
I found it in the `~/.zprofile`！！！
I deleted that file,finally `echo $PATH` shows 
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`