# How to set the environment variable correctly

Tags: macos, shell

Want to add an environment variable to the file to the existing ones, and not create a new file.

Hi! Trying to set environment variables for the program. OS – macOS Monterey
The zsh shell (z shell) is installed on the computer.

1. Run the command

```
echo $PATH
```

2. Get the response

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

3. Creating a new configuration file

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

4. Add the environment variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

5. An environment variable has been created, the command

```
echo $PATH
```

gives the answer

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/path/to/directory
```

Is it possible to add an environment variable without creating a new configuration file (.zsh_profile), i.e. add it to the file where there are already environment variables (step 2 of my actions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOS: How to change PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014749/macos-how-to-change-path-environment-variable)